# Linux: Use maildir instead of mbox

Tags: linux, email, postfix

Is there a way to use Maildir instead of mbox on a Linux box?

On some websites, it is suggested to add to `/etc/aliases`:

```
myuser: /var/mail/myuser/maildir
```

I've issued the `newaliases` command, but it didn't work.

Comment: This is contingent upon your source of mail and your choice of mail clients.

Comment: I'm using Postfix as MTA. It should support Maildir format.

Comment: My point was that it is either the MTA or the MUA that puts the mail in whatever form it is in, so this is a matter of configuring one of those (and probably you should adjust your question to ask about that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you're on Ubuntu...**

Instruct Postfix to use Maildirs instead of Mboxes:

```
sudo postconf -e "home_mailbox = Maildir/"
```

Restart Postfix to make changes effect:

```
sudo  /etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

Check the mailbox of fmaster:

```
su - fmaster
MAIL=/home/fmaster/Maildir
mail
```

You can find complete guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto).

**If you're on CentOS...**

Add following line in /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
home_mailbox = Maildir/
```

A trailing slash indicates Maildir format. To specify mbox format, use `home_mailbox = Mailbox`

You can find complete guide [here](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix).